# React Edit values are not bind in dynamic input select

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-select

I have create an dynamic input select field ,in that field creating editable I am try to bind some data predefined But I am set Data but it takes only index but values are not updated in fields.

My code: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-select-update-n1k9v

Input Fields Data

```
const [roomInputs, setRoomInputs] = useState([
    { boardBasic: "", roomType: "", adult: "", child: "" }
  ]);
```

Predefined Data to set in input fields

```
const updateData = [
  {
    id: "1",
    boardBasic: "roomOnly",
    roomType: "Delux Room",
    adult: "2",
    child: "2"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    boardBasic: "fullBoard",
    roomType: "Delux Room",
    adult: "2",
    child: "2"
  }
];
useEffect(() => {
    roomDataInput();
  }, []);

  const roomDataInput = () => {
    setRoomInputs(updateData);
  };
```

Input Fields

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {roomInputs.map((x, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item sm={12} lg={2} xs={12}>
                <Select
                  name="roomType"
                  placeholder="Room Type"
                  isSearchable
                  value={options.value}
                  options={options2}
                  onChange={(option) =>
                    handleRoomChangeType(option, i, "roomType")
                  }
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item lg={2} sm={12} xs={12}>
                <Select
                  name="boardBasic"
                  placeholder="Board Basic"
                  value={options.value}
                  onChange={(option) =>
                    handleRoomChangeBoard(option, i, "boardBasic")
                  }
                  options={BoardBasic}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sm={12} lg={2} xs={12}>
                <Select
                  name="adult"
                  placeholder="Adult"
                  value={options.value}
                  onChange={(option) =>
                    handleRoomChangeAdult(option, i, "adult")
                  }
                  options={options}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sm={12} lg={2} xs={12}>
                <Select
                  name="child"
                  placeholder="Child"
                  value={options.value}
                  onChange={(option) =>
                    handleRoomChangeChild(option, i, "child")
                  }
                  options={options}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sm={12} lg={2} xs={12}>
                {roomInputs.length !== 1 && (
                  <DeleteIcon
                    onClick={() => handleRemoveClickRoom(i)}
                    style={{
                      marginRight: "10px",
                      marginTop: "4px",
                      cursor: "pointer"
                    }}
                  />
                )}
                {roomInputs.length - 1 === i && (
                  <AddCircleOutlineIcon
                    onClick={handleAddClickRoom}
                    style={{ marginTop: "4px", cursor: "pointer" }}
                  />
                )}
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </div>
        ))}
        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change default `state` value to `updateData` and remove `useEffect`:

```
 const [roomInputs, setRoomInputs] = useState(updateData);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   roomDataInput();
  // }, []);
```

Also set `defaultValue` for all the `select`s in the `map`:

```
{roomInputs.map((x, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item sm={12} lg={2} xs={12}>
                <Select
                  defaultValue={options2.find((y) => y.value == x.roomType)}
                  name="roomType"
                  placeholder="Room Type"
                  isSearchable
                  value={options.value}
                  options={options2}
                  onChange={(option) =>
                    handleRoomChangeType(option, i, "roomType")
                  }
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item lg={2} sm={12} xs={12}>
                <Select
                  defaultValue={BoardBasic.find(
                    (y) => y.value === x.boardBasic
                  )}
                  name="boardBasic"
                  placeholder="Board Basic"
                  value={options.value}
                  onChange={(option) =>
                    handleRoomChangeBoard(option, i, "boardBasic")
                  }
                  options={BoardBasic}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sm={12} lg={2} xs={12}>
                <Select
                  defaultValue={options.find((y) => y.value == x.adult)}
                  name="adult"
                  placeholder="Adult"
                  value={options.value}
                  onChange={(option) =>
                    handleRoomChangeAdult(option, i, "adult")
                  }
                  options={options}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sm={12} lg={2} xs={12}>
                <Select
                  defaultValue={options.find((y) => y.value == x.child)}
                  name="child"
                  placeholder="Child"
                  value={options.value}
                  onChange={(option) =>
                    handleRoomChangeChild(option, i, "child")
                  }
                  options={options}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sm={12} lg={2} xs={12}>
                {roomInputs.length !== 1 && (
                  <DeleteIcon
                    onClick={() => handleRemoveClickRoom(i)}
                    style={{
                      marginRight: "10px",
                      marginTop: "4px",
                      cursor: "pointer"
                    }}
                  />
                )}
                {roomInputs.length - 1 === i && (
                  <AddCircleOutlineIcon
                    onClick={handleAddClickRoom}
                    style={{ marginTop: "4px", cursor: "pointer" }}
                  />
                )}
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </div>
        ))}
```

[image: Edit Dynamic Select Update (forked)]